# Issue in React and SignalR where SignalR connection is not identified

Tags: reactjs, typescript, signalr

Is there any way that we can use react and SignalR together.

I tried out some examples but I was not success.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    const nick = window.prompt('Your name:', 'John');

    //const hubConnection = new HubConnection('http://localhost:5000/chat'); 
    //Said deprecated

    const hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('http://localhost:5000/chat').build();

    this.setState({ hubConnection, nick }, () => {
        this.state.hubConnection
            .start()
            .then(() => console.log('Connection started!'))
            .catch(err => console.log('Error while establishing connection :('));

        this.state.hubConnection.on('sendToAll', (nick, receivedMessage) => {
            const text = `${nick}: ${receivedMessage}`;
            const messages = this.state.messages.concat([text]);
            this.setState({ messages });
        });
    });
}
```

This is an example, where the HubConnection is provided. But when trying to set it to the state hubConnection variable, I'm saying the 'hubConnection variable does not exist on type ReadOnly'

Why I'm receiving this error?

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Per the Redux FAQ, [the right place for websockets and other similar connections is in Redux middleware](https://redux.js.org/faq/codestructure#where-should-websockets-and-other-persistent-connections-live). Some examples online describe how to add SignalR in a component which is a bad practice. Because if your component gets unmounted then signalR instance has to be recreated.
It is easy to create a middleware, and you can use authentication for establishing connection, and you can dispatch action creators based on different messages emitted from SignalR.

This is my custom middleware that establishes the connection, and registers the handlers. Please note that I only would like to receive data, and not interested in sending data. I use REST APIs to send data to server.

```
import {
  JsonHubProtocol,
  HttpTransportType,
  HubConnectionBuilder,
  LogLevel
} from '@aspnet/signalr'; // version 1.0.4

// action for user authentication and receiving the access_token
import { USER_SIGNED_IN } from '../actions/auth';

const onNotifReceived = res => {
  console.log('****** NOTIFICATION ******', res);
};

const startSignalRConnection = connection => connection.start()
  .then(() => console.info('SignalR Connected'))
  .catch(err => console.error('SignalR Connection Error: ', err));

const signalRMiddleware = ({ getState }) => next => async (action) => {
  // register signalR after the user logged in
  if (action.type === USER_SIGNED_IN) {
    const urlRoot = (window.appConfig || {}).URL_ROOT;
    const connectionHub = `${urlRoot}/api/service/hub`;

    const protocol = new JsonHubProtocol();

    // let transport to fall back to to LongPolling if it needs to
    const transport = HttpTransportType.WebSockets | HttpTransportType.LongPolling;

    const options = {
      transport,
      logMessageContent: true,
      logger: LogLevel.Trace,
      accessTokenFactory: () => action.user.access_token
    };

    // create the connection instance
    const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(connectionHub, options)
      .withHubProtocol(protocol)
      .build();

    // event handlers, you can use these to dispatch actions to update your Redux store
    connection.on('OperationProgress', onNotifReceived);
    connection.on('UploadProgress', onNotifReceived);
    connection.on('DownloadProgress', onNotifReceived);

    // re-establish the connection if connection dropped
    connection.onclose(() => setTimeout(startSignalRConnection(connection), 5000));

    startSignalRConnection(connection);
  }

  return next(action);
};

export default signalRMiddleware;
```

And inside my store.js file

```
import signalRMiddleware from '../middlewares/signalRMiddleware';

...

createStore(rootReducer, {}, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(signalRMiddleware)));
```

Comment: What to do when there are multiple `connectionHub`s (more than one hub urls)?

Comment: @Akhilesh , I would say create multiple instances of "connection" with the other hub urls. The new "connection" instances will be able to handle new events on those hub urls.